# Advanced Stylistic Analysis for Python

Tags: python, static-analysis

I teach students Python at my university, and part of my work is to give feedback on basic stylistic choices that they make with their program design. Often, I find myself giving very similar feedback for certain files, for example:

- Use `for ele in my_list` rather than `for i in range(len(my_list))`
- Use `enumerate(my_list)` if you need indexes and values
- Don't call `__magic__` methods on classes
- Use the `in` keyword to check if something is contained within a list or dictionary, rather than a for loop
- Not using built-ins to perform simple tasks (`sum` of list, etc)
- Many other basic stylistic problems (mostly due to them being used to C and other low-level languages)

A lot of these issues seem like things that could be caught programmatically, which would save precious lab time for things like higher-level program design.

Is there a tool that can perform static analysis on code in order to detect and help students fix simple issues like this, preferably in a simple and human-readable format.

I'm looking for something similar to Pylint, but more focused on writing code pythonically than on nitpicky things like trailing white-space.

Comment: Sourcery does some/most  of that (and much more)

Comment: The licensing could be an issue though - when you multiply it to over 1800 students per year for this course alone it adds up a ton, hence I'd prefer an open source tool

Comment: It does have a free version that cover a lot.

Comment: And they are very approachable, so you could probably strike some deal with them

Comment: I'll keep them in mind, but I will still look for an open source option (or see if I can make one at some point)